# not able to execute yum info error showing path is not verify

Tags: fedora, yum

I have encounter a problem when execute yum info , showing error

```
--(error cannot retrieve metalink for repository:fedora.Please verify its path)
```

FYI mine using Fedora release 17

I think the baseurl is old in file fedora-update.repo but im unable to edit it although i'm using terminal . Any help ? Thanks.

Comment: paste the relevant part of the yum repo file that you think is old, and what do you mean by 'unable to edit' ?

Comment: Iamauser, thanks for the advise. I try using nano or gedit but got error.how to modify the repo . as i'm using fedora 17 workstation version.

Comment: yum repos are  in `ls /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo`

Comment: [updates]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch - Updates
failovermethod=priority
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates

Comment: Thanks helping,can you check is above URL link is correct.Thats is on fedora-updates.repo

Comment: Its okay guy im using fedora server and it can update.